# Is it a good practice to always check method arguments even if the passed values have been check before?

Tags: java

Below, in the second method `printFirstArgument()` is it a good practice to double check the method argument's validity?

Since it was check in the first method call `checkInputArguments()`, can we suppose that the passed argument is correct? (Is double checking the argument superfluous?)

My concerns are the following:

- Disadvantage of double checking: code duplication
- Disadvantage of NOT double checking : creates '*temporal coupling*' since the call of the first method `checkInputArguments()` should always come before the second method call.

Which is the correct approach? What are your thought on this topic? What others factors needs to be considered? (e.g. What if the methods were public?)

PS: This is a theoretical question, let's suppose that the methods must not be merged (should be kept separate).

Example code:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    checkInputArguments(args);
    printFirstArgument(args);
}

private static void checkInputArguments(final String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Argument is missing. Proper usage is: ..."); // handle situation by throwing a meaningful error message to the user
    }
}

private static void printFirstArgument(final String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 0) {  // is this check needed?
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Argument is missing. Proper usage is: ...");  // handle situation by throwing a meaningful error message to the user
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The question is too general.. In your specific example, the double check is pure nonsense obviously. In general, we're trying not to duplicate code. As a rule of thumb I would say that only methods called externally should be verified, but this is project-specific or even case-specific... Btw very often when there is some kind of global error handling such checks are not needed at all, nothing is wrong with throwing a runtime exception where this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the `main()` method should not call `checkInputArguments()`, but rather `printFirstArgument()` should call it.

It is not the responsibility of `main()` to check `printFirstArgument()`‘s requirements on behalf of `printFirstArgument()`. Only `printFirstArgument()` should have knowledge of what its requirements are.

Some examples of why this is so:

- `printFirstArgument()` may be called from elsewhere. The caller is relying on the *contract*, not the *implementation*. They won’t know if there’s a requirement to check first
- the implementation may change to gracefully handle there being no first argument, for example by doing nothing. If checks are made before calling, the dev making that change would first have to *know* checks are being made first (requires tribal knowledge) and then comb the code base to find and remove them